# jQuery jqClock plugin options

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

Ok, I'm being stupid today and can't figure how to get this to work:

I have to set the clock plugin like this:

```
$('#clock').clock({"calendar":"false", "format":"24","timestamp":"1303996405"});
```

Where calendar and format I type in manually but the timestamp i collect from the hidden div. And I've tried few stuff like this below:

```
var timestamp = '{"calendar":"false", "format":"24",' + '"timestamp":"' + $('#clockTimestamp').html()  + '"}';
alert(timestamp);     
$('#clock').clock(timestamp);
```

But this clearly doesn't work, so please help me out on this one, so I can slap my self in the face for being dumb again :/

edit:This is the correct solution as helped by suhair:

```
$('#clock').clock({"calendar":"false", "format":"24","timestamp":$('#clockTimestamp').html()*1000});
```

God bless stackoverflow!!!

Comment: in case someone wonders what is the *1000 for: it's because the plugin works with miliseconds and php returns seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quotes for timestamp not needed.
Here is the corrected code demo
http://jsfiddle.net/Cd7BX/

Hope this is what you want to accompilsh

Edit: I have pasted the entire plugin code in the fiddle itself that is why the cryptic code at top.

Comment: @suhari: thank you very much, you just saved the day! Ill add the code to my edited post now, just to have a reference on the right solution...